# Help with modified LP grill - how to take apart

Tags: stone, propane

I inherited this Williams Sonoma SGIR27lp grill, came with a house we moved in. It is modified, instead of the grille and burners on the top, there is just a large stone/granite (?) plate. I managed to find a manual online, but it only has basic installation procedures. I am fairly handy, but have no experience with repairing grills.
The large plate is glued with some super-strong cement/epoxy, I've been trying to cut underneath for an hour, but cannot separate it from the body. The body itself is all riveted, not a single screw that could help disassemble it from underneath. Ok, now to the specific questions:
(a) any idea how to separate the top, in order to see what's left of the burner mechanism? or to disassemble from the bottom?
(b) there is a metal pipe in the back, seemingly cut... (see the pic). what is it for?

[image: front]
[image: Back]
[image: Cut pipe]
[image: all glued]
[image: Inside]

Comment: Maybe someone turned an old grill into a table?

Answer (score 1):

After 2 hours of struggling I managed to remove the top. It took a machete and a long back saw and some mineral spirits  :)
Underneath is a semi-functional grill, missing a few parts and the grilles. I think I have a pretty good idea how to fix it from here on  ;)

Answer (score -1):

The pipe is for an auxiliary burner. I would remove the "T" at the regulator to get rid of that line. Then connect the regulator to the single tube to the grill.